# Email to Case (on demand) forwarding via Outlook rules

Tags: case, outlook, email2case, gmail

I am having trouble to forward e-mails coming into my Outlook Exchange Inbox into the Salesforce environment (creating a case). 
I have managed to do this in Gmail, since it's fairly easy to do so. Just followed the link: 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?siteLang=en_us&id=000170989&type=1

It looks like there is no proper answer on the internet for using this function with Outlook 2013, as I can't find any specific documentation on how to do this in combination with Salesforce.

Are there any other experiences about this?

I would love to hear.

**EDIT: I'll break it down for more understanding:**

I want exactly the following:
-Forward a copy of incoming mail to "E2C - Salesforce Email Services Address" **AND** keep Gmail's copy in the inbox. + Enabling IMAP.

The method above worked for my E2C-on-demand mechanism in Salesforce: All emails i receive on that **Gmail**, would become a case **IF** there is no REF ID involved. However, when there **IS** a REF ID involved: the sent (inbound) emails would be logged under the right case.

As for Outlook 2013... It seems to be *IMPOSSIBLE* to re-produce the same method within the "Manage Rules & Alerts" options in Outlook. 
As I have 1. my personal inbox email, 2. a functional mailbox. I want the ruling to be applied on only the **functional mailbox**. Once i enable the created ruling for my entire Microsoft Exchange account (meaning personal + functional mailboxes, which is actually something i don't want) it will produce an error anyway.

Ruling: Apply this rule after the message arrives 
on this computer only 
forward it to "E2C - Salesforce Email Services Address" 
and move a copy to the x folder

After this i realized i should use **redirect** instead of forwarding:

Apply this rule after the message arrives 
redirect it to "E2C - Salesforce Email Services Address"

Bottom line, both methods don't work.

**Also** there is something extra which is not gonna work out for us as well:
"The rule will only run when you check your email in Outlook. If Outlook isn't running, this rule won't work for email you check online or from another device."

Comment: Create a Distribution list in Outlook and add the E2C routing Address in the Distribution list and Try .

Comment: Creative. But unfortunately it did not work

Answer (score 4):

I think your issue might be with how you're handling the inbound email from Outlook/Exchange.  If you're "Forwarding" the email to the unique SFDC email address, then it is in fact coming from your support email address.  Try "Redirecting" the email instead.  This should preserve the users From address.

Answer (score -1):

This should help: https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/how-to-set-up-auto-forwarding-in-outlook-2013

Essentially, lists down the steps to forward emails that you receive from Outlook 2013.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Can you please include the relevant content? Links tend to break over time answers without detail useless in the long run.